Unable to load admin styles in a WordPress block plugin
I am using this code to enqueue my WordPress admin specific stylesheet.
function enqueue_neatwp_admin_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'plugin-admin-style', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'build/styles/admin.css', array(), '1.0.0' );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_plugin_admin_styles' );

This works if there is already a CSS file in the build/styles directory. However, the npm run start command will not copy the CSS file in the src/styles directory to the build/styles directory.
I cannot use the src/styles directory link because I am guessing the plugin will only ship with the contents of the build directory.
How do I ensure that my admin CSS is included and loaded?
Thanks.

Could you please share the configuration of the webpack.config.js  file, this helps us in understanding this issue.

Hi @NarendraSishodiya. Thanks. There is no webpack.config.js file in my plugin directory. I created it using the WordPress create-block package. I have a package.json file. I had intenret connectivity issues so couldn't comment earlier. :)

The contents of src/styles/* can be included in the plugin by adding the file field to your block-name/package.json with the folder to include:
package.json
{
    "name": "block-name", // your block
     ...
    "files": [
        "src/styles/*"
    ]
}

As you created the block with @wordpress/create-block, you can use npm run plugin-zip to build your block plugin to include all files under src/styles into the final plugin.zip file.
Note: the file path in the zip will be src/styles/ not build/styles so remember to update wp_enqueue_style path to match.
The Enqueuing assets in the Editor documentation may also be helpful if your admin.css is block specific.
